# Calculate probability based on cost and time

Tags: python, math, statistics, probability

I have an input of cost values and want to calculate probabilities for each value that varies based on elapsed time. Lower costs should have a higher probability at first, but should taper off and allow the higher costs to have a greater share of probability as time goes on.

For example with time = 0

```
costs = [0, 2, 3, 5]
time = 0
expected_result = [0.99, 0.005, 0.003, 0.002] #should sum to 1.0
```

On the next iteration, time = 1

```
costs = [0, 2, 3, 5]
time = 1
expected_result = [0.95, 0.025, 0.015, 0.01]
```

Later after an arbitrarily longer time...

```
costs = [0, 2, 3, 5]
time = 10
expected_result = [0.5, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1]
```

I wasn't able to find a similar problem to learn from, but that might be because I'm not sure of the correct search terms for what I'm trying to achieve.

EDIT:

To provide some context, I am designing an agent in a game that makes a decision by selecting an action at every arbitrarily long time step. Actions incur a cost in the form of in-game resources, or expected results, and I want to make the agent begin the game by selecting safer, less expensive actions but behave in a riskier manner as the game evolves. The general idea is that I want to codify a sense of urgency and simulate that behavior in a Markov Decision Process that considers cost and time in computing transition probabilities. Costs are mapped to actions and have been computed apriori. Below is code that approximates the desired results.

```
def calculate_probability(costs, time):
    probabilities = []
    adjustment = 0.001  # To avoid division by zero
    rate = 15
    for c in costs:
        probabilities.append(1 / ((c + adjustment) + ((time + adjustment) / rate)))
    return [p / sum(probabilities) for p in probabilities]  # scale values


costs = [0, 2, 3, 5]
time = 0
probabilities = calculate_probability(costs, time)
print("costs: {} time: {}".format(costs, time))
print("probabilities: {}".format(probabilities))

time = 1
probabilities = calculate_probability(costs, time)
print("costs: {} time: {}".format(costs, time))
print("probabilities: {}".format(probabilities))

time = 10
probabilities = calculate_probability(costs, time)
print("costs: {} time: {}".format(costs, time))
print("probabilities: {}".format(probabilities))
```

Results:

```
costs: [0, 2, 3, 5] time: 0
probabilities: [0.9988994464993101, 0.0005324623915241525, 0.0003550380119066324, 0.00021305309725910417]
costs: [0, 2, 3, 5] time: 1
probabilities: [0.9361523759693375, 0.03066581164511371, 0.020669567411005885, 0.012512244974542817]
costs: [0, 2, 3, 5] time: 10
probabilities: [0.6450909018718866, 0.16146617535857696, 0.11744275252924269, 0.07600017024029376]
```

Comment: What you probably want is some kind of polynomial that'll produce this sort of distribution. I don't honestly think you'll get an answer here.

Comment: Have you already defined a function that takes time and cost and produces an expected result, or is that what you're after?

Comment: Sorry, yes the function is what I'm after.

Comment: Sounds like a Markov chain to me: more recent results have a greater effect than those in the past.

Comment: For context, the probabilities I'm looking to calculate are for a Markov process - where my goal is to initially select the lowest cost actions but over time increase the likelihood of selecting costlier actions.